Ubuntu won't load after screen freeze
I was working merrily when my screen froze, after waiting a bit I had to force shutdown my pc using the power button. after trying to boot again I was hit with these messages during boot.
[    0.177253] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol \_SB.PC00.I2C0.TPD0], AE_NOT_FOUND (20230331/dswload2-162)
[    0.177266] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20230331/ps object-220)
[    0.177287] ACPI BIOS Error (bug_ Could not resolve symbol \_SB.PC00.I2C0.TPL1], AE_NOT_FOUND (20230331/dswload2-162)
[    0.177290] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20230331/ps object-220)
[    1.823349] pci 10000:e1:00.0: BAR 0: error updating (0x5200004 != 0xffffffff)
[    1.823369] pci 10000:e1:00.0: BAR 0: error updating (high 0x000000 != 0xffffffff)
[    2.147732] nvme 10000:e1:00.0: Unable to change power state from D3cold to D0, device inaccessible
Gave up waiting for suspend/resume device
Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:
  - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
    - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
  - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! UUID=[<a random uuid here>] does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built in command.

(initramfs) _

It's worth noting that I also have windows on my laptop and it's booting fine (it's on a different SSD from Ubuntu)
My laptop is a lenovo ideapad Gaming, with 2 SSDs as follows:

NVMe INTEL SSDPEKNW512GZL (the one with windows)
NVMe TwinMOS SSD (the one with ubuntu)

